# Getting an exact reference for a selected text in HTML

Tags: javascript, css

Let's assume that I have the following text within a single `<p>... </p>`

When a user selects a couple of words within the text, lets assume the **first** `Quisque vestibulum` is selected, I get the selected text with `window.getSelection().toString();` then I apply some CSS tricks, lets say I underline the text.

When the user comes back one month later, I would like to underline same text again. How can I get an exact reference for the selected text for future reference? I don't want to highlight the **second** `Quisque vestibulum`.

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum at
>   dolor sit amet augue tempor venenatis vitae et nibh. Donec dignissim
>   fringilla fermentum. In facilisis consectetur risus. Nam vel mauris
>   magna, a feugiat nisl. Quisque vestibulum, neque eu tristique
>   tristique, tortor mauris ornare magna, at ultricies augue orci sed
>   enim. Nulla magna ligula, dapibus vel commodo ac, sodales ut sem. Duis
>   lorem massa, consectetur sed molestie eget, posuere eu magna.
>   Pellentesque sollicitudin mattis facilisis. Nunc pulvinar metus et
>   diam dignissim sit amet pellentesque metus pretium. Quisque vestibulum, maecenas vel leo
>   sit amet diam iaculis sollicitudin.

Comment: You need cookies to start with

Comment: Can the text change over time ?

Comment: @Garreh Yes, it is likely.

Comment: I don't think there is a way to get the "reference" of text. Text is not object or element. It's just a combination of some characters... The only way I know to locate a piece of text is by the offset to the start position. So you may need to implement your own logic to locate the text you want.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the search() or indexOf() and store the position of the string as well as the actual selected text.